# Unable to increase image size

Tags: html, css, image

I would really like to increase the image size on my blog. At the moment the images are quite small.

My theme is using the 960 grid system and I'm unable to work out how to increase the image size. My 960 grid system looks like this

```
/* Standard 960px ----------- */

.grid_1                             { width:48px; }
.grid_2                             { width:128px; }
.grid_3                             { width:208px; }
.grid_4                             { width:588px; }
.grid_5                             { width:368px; }        
.grid_6                             { width:448px; }
.grid_7                             { width:528px; }
.grid_8                             { width:960px; }
.grid_9                             { width:688px; }
.grid_10                            { width:768px; }
.grid_11                            { width:848px; }
.grid_12                            { width:960px; }

.column                             { margin:0 16px 0 16px; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:inline; }
.row                                { margin:0 auto; width:960px; overflow:hidden; }
.row .row                           { margin:0 -16px 0 -16px; width:auto; display:inline-block; }
```

In my CSS, the only way to control the images is under

```
.posts .post.photo div img{
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align:bottom; 
}
```

But when I add a width and height to this, the images are distorted. Is there any way for the images to be bigger without distorting them?

Here is a link to the full css - http://jsfiddle.net/x8P6w/

Comment: Can you ad link to your blog, or a fiddle something so we could figure out the problem.

Comment: Make the actual images bigger. Making a small image bigger than the resolution of the underlying image will **always** distort

Comment: Modify px size to suit: `{ width: 100px; height: auto; }` or `{ width: auto; height: 100px; }`. This will maintain the existing aspect ratios

Comment: Change the size of the actual image. Increasing the width and height will always distort the image

Comment: Here's the full css http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/lHimw7ktm/amazium.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on responsive design, the image size has been a huge problematic over the years. You can make the image either take the size it has from fabric, that is to say

```
.img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or you can do a few other things:

Use of plugins:

I recommend the following->

https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill - Picturefill

Or you can do it your way by serving the correct image size according to your needs.

This last one involves the use of media queries to know the size of the viewport and which image you're going to use or which css class you are going to use.

A VERY deep explanation of the basics of media queries can be found on this amazing site:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realise now that the css quotes media queries quite a lot, but I think this only applies to when viewed responsive. Here's the css http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/lHimw7ktm/amazium.css

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering that by "Distorted" you mean they are not proportional, in that case, set only a width or height value (not both) and the remaining value will increasy proportional to the size of the image.

Example:

```
.image{ 
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}

.new-height{
height: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Firstly I found that by editing "grid_3" width, the picture height and width increased. Secondly, I added to the grid css this -

```
.column                             { margin:0 0px 0 0px; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:inline; }
.row                                { margin:0 auto; width:1035px; overflow:hidden; }
.row .row                           { margin:0 -10px 0 -10px; width:auto; display:inline-block; }
```

And increased the .row width to 1035px.